# How can I change the VoiceOver language for a song on my 6th gen iPod Nano?

Tags: itunes, language, voiceover, ipod-nano, accessibility

Is it possible to change language used for reading song album/artist/title for certain songs? I.e. when I use slovak as default iPod nano language, but I have songs with english titles, I would like to hear those in english. I think this was available for previous iPod nanos, but I cannot find it in iTunes when syncing songs to 6th gen nano.

**Update:** This is how Options panel looks when I right-click on song stored on my iPod Nano (6th gen):

[image: iTunes Options panel]

VoiceOver language is not there :-(

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the song (you can select more than one), select "Get Info", choose the Options tab, and pick English for the voice over language.

[image: Screenshot of the Get Info panel]

If you don't see this in your info panel it means that the VoiceOver Kit is not installed: Follow the instructions on this [KB Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3870) to download and install it.

However those instructions do work on the Shuffle and the 5th generation Nano, but I just tried my daugther's 6th generation Nano and the check box is not there. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I remembered, unfortunately there isn't "VoiceOver Language" field in my iTunes. See my updated question for screenshot.

Comment: VoiceOver still works fine though, it just isn't enabled in iTunes anymore, but inside iPod Nano itself. I think new iPod Nano 6th gen now generates voice messages on the fly.

Comment: Do you have the "iPodVoiceOver.framework" in "/Library/Application Support/iTunes"? I've added instructions on how to install the VoiceOver Kit.

Comment: Sorry, just checked with a 6th generation Nano, the checkbox to enable voice over is not there. Worth a try maybe is to plug an iPod that support voice over to force install the kit and see if the individual song selection shows up and works with the Nano...

Comment: interesting idea. Will try that when I have a chance.

Comment: Is there a way to set default? It's 'auto' actually, but it uses english while I want italian.